# Is this the correct way to INSERT a row in an Oracle database?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, zend-framework, insert

I am have created a web app that will use PHP to insert a row into an Oracle database. I am using Zend Framework to connect to the database. When I test it I dont get any errors but I dont see that added row in the table.

Here is my code:

```
$remote = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   

// Connect with PDO
$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_OCI', 
array(
  'dbname' => $dbname,
  'username' => $dbuser,
  'password' => $dbpass
)
);

$req = "INSERT INTO " . $dbtable . " (id, url, adddate, addip) VALUES ('', '" . $safeurl . "', SYSDATE, '" . $remote . "')";
$res = $db->prepare($req);
$res->execute();
```

`$safeurl` is generated by user input, and it is sanitized.
`id` is autogenerated when you insert the row.

Please help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: How is `id` autogenerated, and if it is, why have it in the column list?  Also, did you try typing in the same exact INSERT command in SQLPlus or something to see if it works?

Comment: Yes i typed it in using Oracle Instant CLient with SQL Plus and worked like a charm. I just can't get PHP to do it on it's own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to commit. Each update/insert/delete begins a new transaction if it's not started. So issue another `COMMIT` statement after inserting a record (or a bunch of records). Oracle doesn't have autocommit mode.

Comment: Typically PDO will auto commit.

Comment: Sure, you can do it with PDO, it would be even better (`$db->commit()`), but I doubt that it's done automatically...

Answer (score 0):

after

```
 $res = $db->prepare($req);
```

do `echo $req->__toString();` to get the generated query then copy it and execute it in SQL Plus 
if it works then your only issue is that you need to commit:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$req = "INSERT INTO " . $dbtable . " (id, url, adddate, addip) VALUES ('', '" . $safeurl . "', SYSDATE, '" . $remote . "')";
$res = $db->prepare($req);
$res->execute();
$db->commit();
```